# execute immediate errors

Tags: amazon-redshift, plpgsql

I'm using Amazon RedShift SQL (used to use Oracle many years ago) and am getting constant syntax errors every way that I try EXECUTE IMMEDIATE. I have even copied and posted code from PostgreSQL documentation pages (e.g. using sprintf) but to no avail. I reckon the below should work...?

```
declare 
  stm varchar(200);
begin
  stm =  'GRANT SELECT, INSERT, TRIGGER, UPDATE, DELETE, REFERENCES, RULE ON public.angus TO adcd;';
  execute immediate stm;
end;
```

Amazon Invalid operation: syntax error at or near "varchar"

Comment: So you have learned that you cannot use Oracle syntax for Redshift.

Comment: no I never used execute immediate when using Oracle. I've read the documentation for PostgreSQL but my code (above) doesn't want to work so I'm hoping someone will tell me where I went wrong. IS the above Oracle-only code? I wouldn't know

Comment: I tried this as well:
    sprintf(command,  "GRANT SELECT, INSERT, TRIGGER, UPDATE, DELETE, REFERENCES, RULE ON public.angus TO adbd");
    execute immediate :command;

Comment: The problem is nothing to do with EXECUTE IMMEDIATE; it is to do with the DECLARE statement you're trying to use.  There's at least a chance that DECLARE name … starts a cursor declaration — except that VARCHAR isn't a valid start to the statement (under this hypothesis, it probably requires FOR as the next keyword).

Comment: Ah thanks!
But how come this doesnt work?

stm =  'GRANT SELECT, INSERT, TRIGGER, UPDATE, DELETE, REFERENCES, RULE ON public.angus TO adbd;'
execute immediate stm;

Comment: and it doesn't work if I remove the immediate either

Comment: Please do not tag Redshift questions with `postgresql`. Although they have some very, very old common roots, those are two very different database products.

Comment: In Postgres you wouldn't even need dynamic SQL to execute a `GRANT` statement. PL/pgSQL (unlike PL/SQL) can run DDL statements without the workaround of using dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. You use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, which you cannot have found in the PostgreSQL documentation, since it is Oracle syntax. The PL/pgSQL statement is `EXECUTE`.
2. You are trying to execute PL/pgSQL code as SQL statement, which won't work.

   Use a `DO` statement:

   ```
   DO $$DECLARE
      ...
   END;$$;
   ```

Comment: THANKS, WIL TRY THAT. I GOT EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FROM HERE: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ecpg-sql-execute-immediate.html

Comment: @Angus: additionally: dynamic SQL (`execute ..`)  isn't needed to run a GRANT statement to begin with

Comment: yes I know, however am hoping to put it in a procedure to grant access to various tables/users by passing in parameters. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for a standalone anonymous block slightly different, also the code is actually submitted as a string. See Postgres [DO](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-do.html) and search Dollar Quoting. Try

```
Do $$
declare 
  stm varchar(200);
begin
  stm =  'GRANT SELECT, INSERT, TRIGGER, UPDATE, DELETE, REFERENCES, RULE ON public.angus TO adcd;';
  execute immediate stm;
end;
$$
```

Comment: There is no `execute immediate` in Postgres

Comment: True, that would just be "execute stm". I didn't edit the existing code; just added  the appropriate DO structure.